# Reference 3.5 assembly from 2.0 application?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0, assemblies, reference

I have an assembly that is targeted for .NET 3.5.

I have an application targeted for .NET 2.0 and wonder if I should have any trouble referencing the 3.5 assembly from the 2.0 application.

I understand that the IL is supposedly the same, so I'm assuming that it will work, but would like to hear some experiences from others who have tried this.

The runtime environment will have both 2.0 and 3.5 installed.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. While the answers given are correct as far as they go, I would like to know a way of quickly identifying the referenced assemblies that require .Net Version 3.5 so that I can, if possible, bring them back to 2.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no problem. There is only one runtime version executing the app. .NET Framework v2.0.

Answer (score 4):

However - when deploying your .net2.0 application, your user will be prompted to install .net3.5 (as there is a .net 3.5 assembly referenced).